# Height of view changes upon calculation?

Tags: swift, uiview, view, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

Swift 3

I have a view with some labels in it that I'm animating into the field of view when a user taps a button. I've used this identical code in another view controller and it worked just fine. For some reason, though, I can't get it to work now. It's always off by 1.5 pixels. Really weird.

This is what is supposed to happen: The scene loads, and the view is hidden to start. The user taps the "show details" button, and the view slides down into view.

But what happens is this: The scene loads and the view is hidden. So far so good. The user taps the "show details button", and the button doesn't do anything. It just slides down a negligible amount. Then the user taps it again, and it finally reveals the view. Why the two taps? I don't know.

I had the console print out the height of the view, and when the scene first loads, the view is at 237.0 for height, but when I tap the button, the height becomes 235.5. Why? This is really puzzling me.

Here's the code:

```
class Step5IncomeSummaryVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var detailsView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var showDetailsButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    showDetailsButton.setTitle("show details", for: .normal)
    viewTop.constant = -(detailsView.bounds.height)
    detailsView.isHidden = true
    print("Initial view height: \(detailsView.bounds.height)")          // check height of view BEFORE animation

}


@IBAction func showDetailsButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Button pressed view height: \(detailsView.bounds.height)")           // check height of view AFTER button press
    if viewTop.constant == -(detailsView.bounds.height) {
        detailsView.isHidden = false
        showDetailsButton.setTitle("hide details", for: .normal)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { 
            self.viewTop.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
        print("After animation view height: \(detailsView.bounds.height)")         // check height of view after animation
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { 
            self.viewTop.constant = -(self.detailsView.bounds.height)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
        showDetailsButton.setTitle("show details", for: .normal)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            self.detailsView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not positive this would be a problem but have you tried moving the code where you actually change the constraint constant *out* of the animation blocks? Move it to the line right above the animation (leaving the `layoutIfNeeded` call in the animation code).

Comment: Two comments:

1. If I move the constraint constant **out** of the animation block, then I won't get the desired animation. The whole point of the constraint in the animation block is to animate the view.

2. At one point I ran the code without the animation blocks, just printing the view height `detailsView.bounds.height`, and I ran into the same problem: the view height changed when I tapped the button. Really weird.

Comment: You *will* get the animation as long as `layoutIfNeeded` is in the animation block. That is how I've normally done it. As for your second point, that indicates you might have an issue with your constraint hierarchy causing it to break constraints that it can't fulfill. When you see the issue occurring, are there any autolayout errors in the console or if you pull up the view debugger?

Comment: I think the issue somehow lies with the fact that I'm using auto constraints to determine the height of the view, rather than hard-coding a definitive height. I want the view to be able to change size depending on the device, and hard-coding the value would defeat that purpose. I'm kind of stumped.

Comment: You're right in that it has something to do with the constraints, but moving them out of the animation didn't make a difference. I had to add a hard-coded constraint in order for the view to animate properly. It's not perfect, and it doesn't translate well to the other devices for preview, but it'll have to do. I'll play around with it more later. There's got to be a simple solution.